# How can I display the current date in PHP in the CYYMMDD format?

Tags: php, sql, date, ibm-midrange

I am trying to find a way to get the current date in to the CYYMMDD format so that I can do an SQL call to our AS400. Does anyone have an easy way of doing this in PHP or will I have to create an RPG program to do it?

Century - Year - Month - Date

Example:

1/27/2014 would convert to 1140127
and
1/26/2014 would convert to 1140126

Thanks!

Comment: Use a combination of `date()` and `strtotime()` or use a `DateTime` object. EDIT: Had no idea what the C was for, you could just use a division on the year

Comment: For those PHP developers who aren't proficient with AS/400, can you explain what C means exactly? In real-life centuries we've already reached 21st.

Comment: Here is a link if you are confused about the C, I was. http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/cyymmdd-format-in-db2/#.

Comment: It's the number of centuries since 1900.  Just subtract 19000000 from CCYYMMDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = (date('Y') >= 2000? 1 : 0) . date('ymd');
echo $str;
```

Comment: Let's leave the 2100 effect to the following generations :)

Comment: Hack for the 2100+ problem:)

$str = (($n = date('Y')) >= 2000? intval(($n-2000)/100)+1 : 0) . date('ymd');
echo $str;

Answer (score 1):

Convert a full *YYYYMMDD* format into *CYYMMDD* format by subtracting 19000000:

For example:

```
<?php echo date('Ymd') - 19000000 ?>
```

Comment: Your comment to this effect has two upvotes, while your answer (entered much later) has none (prior to mine).  Had you just gone straight for an answer instead of commenting, you'd probably have earned more rep!

Comment: @JohnY I didn't think it was worthy of a dedicated answer until I saw the hack for handling 2100+.  Thanks for the upvote!